# Named coordinates: How to spell?

Tags: terminology, writing

I'm uncertain which is the proper writing for x/y/z-coordinates :

- With a space, like so : X Coordinate? Or with a hyphen (X-Coordinate)?
- Capitalize X or leave it lower case? I tend to choose lower case.
- Capitalize "Coordinate"? I guess no.

My favourite until now is "x-coordinate".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "x" is the mathematical symbol.  In mathematical use, variables are written with italic. However, this typographical nice effect is not always used. In mathematics the uppercase a different symbol from the lowercase. For example *V* might be "volume" but *v* is velocity. The *x* is lowercase. Try to avoid starting a sentence with a mathematical symbol; rephrase if you have to.

We normally hyphenate between the *x* and the word. So you can write.

> The *x*-coordinate shows the position on the *x*-axis.